# Redefintition of SidebarDelegate as different kind of symbol

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the following Objective C code that **keeps** error complaining I am redefining it when I not!! I am trying to implement a NSTableViewDelegate thing but xcode keep complaining

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // add Hello World to sidebar
    [self.Sidebar.tableView insertValue:0 atIndex:0 inPropertyWithKey:@"Hello World!"];

    [self.Sidebar.tableView setDelegate: SidebarDelegate()]

    // reload data
    [self.Sidebar.tableView reloadData];


}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
    return YES;
}

@end

// Sidebar Delage

@implementation SidebarDelegate : NSObject <NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>;

// setting data
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    anObject = @"Apples";
}

// height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    return 20;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)rowIndex);
    return ((long)rowIndex % 2) == 0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return 4;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
[self.Sidebar.tableView setDelegate: SidebarDelegate()];
```

with

```
SidebarDelegate *sidebarDelegate = [[SidebarDelegate alloc] init];
[self.Sidebar.tableView setDelegate:sidebarDelegate];
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
[self.Sidebar.tableView setDelegate: SidebarDelegate()];
```

implicitly creates a function named `SidebarDelegate()` of the form

```
int SidebarDelegate(void)
```

Thus, when you try to define a class of the same name, you overwrite the symbol in an unacceptable way.  You need to initialize an instance of `SidebarDelegate` and pass that as the TableView's delegate not, I will presume, just pass the name of the class.